# VueJS - How to check an array on matching values?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I'm working on a `couponcode` VueJS app, in which I want to check an array with different `discountcodes` on matching values. Below I have an array with two `discountcodes`. If the button is clicked, I want to check the array for any matches. I am not sure what would be the best solution for this..

```
<template>
    <div class="container">

        <input placeholder='type discount' v-model="discountInput">
        <button @click="checkDiscount">check for discount</button>

        <span class="alert" v-if="discountValid">
            Code juist
        </span>

        <span class="alert" v-if="discountInvalid">
            Code onjuist
        </span>

    </div>
</template>

<script>

  export default {

    props: {

    },

    data: () => {
        return {
            discountInput: '',
            discountValid: false,
            discountInvalid: false,
            discountCodes: [
                { code: 'discount-code-1', message: '10% discount' },
                { code: 'discount-code-2', message: '5 dollar discount' }
            ]

        }
    },
    components: {

    },
    methods: {

        checkDiscount() {
            if (this.discountInput === this.discountCode) {
                return true;
            } else {
                return false;
            }
        }

    },
    watch: {

    }
}
</script>
```

Comment: Good answers already, but to explain your problem… in checkDiscount you're comparing `this.discountInput === this.discountCode` but _there is no_ `discountCode`. You have `discountCodes` with an **s** but not a singular `discountCode`.  `checkDiscount` needs to iterate the array of `discountCodes` (with  s), and you can't compare `discountInput` to the array element (let's say "d") because `d` is an _object_ and the input is a _string_. To find a  match you have to find `d.code` that matches `discountInput`. The `find` and `some` suggested in answers are a great way to iterate with a lambda.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A [find](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) should work.

```
  checkDiscount() {
    if (this.discountCodes.find(x => x.code === this.discountInput)) {
      return true;
    } else {
      return false;
    }
  }
```

or as comments pointed out could be reduced to:

```
  checkDiscount() {
    return !!this.discountCodes.find(x => x.code === this.discountInput);
  }
```

Comment: Anything of the form `if (condition) { return true; } else { return false; }` can always be reduced to `return (condition)` —— `return (this.discountCodes.find(x => x.code === this.discountInput))`

Comment: This could also be written as `return !!this.discountCodes.find(x => x.code === this.discountInput)`

Comment: If he wants only true/false then `some()` is better. Looking at the view template he will probably need to get the actual array element data seeing there's a message field, in which case  the above `find()` example will point him in the right direction.

Answer (score 2):

Try to use array `some`  method as follows :

```
 checkDiscount() {

            return this.discountCodes.some(dis => dis.code === this.discountInput)

        }
```